# Replace SQLite to LocalDb for unittesting for a ABP.io project

Tags: entity-framework-core, abp

I am working with ABP and I used the basic setup which is generated by the abp cli with EF Core and SQL Server.

Now, I would like to replace SQLite (the generated one), with a LocalDb database, since I using spatial data for unit- and integration testing.

However, I am not sure how to make the replacement. I have identified the file which initialize the SQLite, and it is reseeded after each unittest.

When switching to LocalDb, I will not flush / seed database, and I think I have solved that out.

This is the generated file `...\ABPProject\aspnet-core\ABPProject.EntityFrameworkCore.Tests\EntityFrameworkCore\ABPProjectEntityFrameworkCoreTestModule.cs` that uses SQLite, can you please give me an example / ideas how to use LocalDb instead of SQLite?

```
[DependsOn(
    typeof(ABPProjectEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(ABPProjectTestBaseModule),
    typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkCoreSqliteModule)
    )]
public class ABPProjectEntityFrameworkCoreTestModule : AbpModule
{
    private SqliteConnection _sqliteConnection;

    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        ConfigureInMemorySqlite(context.Services);
    }

    private void ConfigureInMemorySqlite(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _sqliteConnection = CreateDatabaseAndGetConnection();

        services.Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Configure(context =>
            {
                context.DbContextOptions.UseSqlite(_sqliteConnection);
            });
        });
    }

    public override void OnApplicationShutdown(ApplicationShutdownContext context)
    {
        _sqliteConnection.Dispose();
    }

    private static SqliteConnection CreateDatabaseAndGetConnection()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ABPProjectDbContext>()
            .UseSqlite(connection)
            .Options;

        using (var context = new ABPProjectDbContext(options))
        {
            context.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().CreateTables();
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really simple. Just do this:

```
namespace ABPProject.EntityFrameworkCore;

[DependsOn(
    typeof(ABPProjectEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
    typeof(ABPProjectTestBaseModule),
    typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkCoreSqliteModule)
    )]
public class ABPProjectEntityFrameworkCoreTestModule : AbpModule
{
    private SqliteConnection _sqliteConnection;

    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        //ConfigureInMemorySqlite(context.Services);
        ConfigureLocalDb(context.Services);
    }

    private void ConfigureInMemorySqlite(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _sqliteConnection = CreateDatabaseAndGetConnection_Sqlite();

        services.Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Configure(context =>
            {
                context.DbContextOptions.UseSqlite(_sqliteConnection);
            });
        });
    }

    private void ConfigureLocalDb(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Configure(context =>
            {
                context.DbContextOptions.UseSqlServer("Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=ABPProject_Unittest;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True");
            });
        });
    }

    public override void OnApplicationShutdown(ApplicationShutdownContext context)
    {
        if (_sqliteConnection is not null)
        {
            _sqliteConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private static SqliteConnection CreateDatabaseAndGetConnection_Sqlite()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ABPProjectDbContext>()
            .UseSqlite(connection, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite())
            .Options;

        using (var context = new ABPProjectDbContext(options))
        {
            context.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().CreateTables();
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

Then you need to disable re-seeding each time between test in `aspnet-core\test\ABPProject.TestBase\ABPProjectTestBaseModule.cs`

```
public override void OnApplicationInitialization(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
    {
        //SeedTestData(context);
    }
```

How to reset the database when starting all tests? Use XUnit collections, which enable setup before all tests are starting and teardown after all tests are executed.

You can read more about it here https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context but basically, you create a new class (NOTE! You need to place this file in each test project, since the class can not be shared between different test projects):

```
public class DatabaseFixture : ABPProjectTestBase<ABPProjectEntityFrameworkCoreTestModule>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    // ... create your shared vars here


    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        IDbContextProvider<ABPProjectDbContext> _dbContextProvider = GetRequiredService<IDbContextProvider<ABPProjectDbContext>>();
        IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager = GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWorkManager>();
        IDataSeeder _dataSeeder = GetRequiredService<IDataSeeder>();

        using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
        {
            var context = await _dbContextProvider.GetDbContextAsync();
            var tableNames = context.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                    .Where(t => t.GetTableName().StartsWith("App"))
                    .Select(t => t.GetTableName())
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();

            // Disable constraints
            foreach (var tableName in tableNames)
            {
                await context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync($"ALTER TABLE {tableName} NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL");
            }

            // Remove rows
            foreach (var tableName in tableNames)
            {
                await context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync($"DELETE FROM {tableName}");
            }

            // Re-enable constraints
            foreach (var tableName in tableNames)
            {
                await context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync($"ALTER TABLE {tableName} CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL");
            }
        }

        // Re - seed database
        await _dataSeeder.SeedAsync();
    }

    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        // ... clean up test data from the database with and use async calls here...
    }
}

[CollectionDefinition("Database collection")]
public class DatabaseCollection : ICollectionFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
    // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
    // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
    // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.
}
```

The last thing is to decorate each test class with following:

```
namespace ABPProject.Things
{
    [Collection("Database collection")]
    public class ThingAppService_Tests : ABPProjectApplicationTestBase
    {
        public readonly DatabaseFixture _fixture;
        private readonly IThingAppService _thingAppService;
        public ThingAppService_Tests(DatabaseFixture fixture)
        {
            _fixture = fixture;
            _thingAppService = GetRequiredService<IThingAppService>();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task GetListAsync_Should_Get_all_Things()
        {
            // This is a test
        }

    }
}
```